# A Life Giver and a Killer

Tags: riddle

> I help your society live, but I can bring it to its knees
>
> My effects on you are obvious so that everyone can see
>
> I'm one of many beings that all have origins the same
>
> Some can kill you easily and some are much more tame
>
> I can make you happy any time of day
>
> As long as the evil grey will just stay away
>
> As the eras go by I will have no choice but to eat you whole
>
> Then after, I will turn white because I am done and full

**What am I?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Could you be

> The sun?

I help your society live, but I can bring it to its knees

> Life requires the energy/ heat from the sun. The sun can bring you to your knees in solar storms, explained in comments.

My effects on you are obvious so that everyone can see

> You can see because of the sun!

I'm one of many beings that all have origins the same

> One of many stars

Some can kill you easily and some are much more tame

> Not sure, maybe radiation causing cancer? EDIT: As explained in comments, some stars have stronger gravity than others and can therefore kill you easier.

I can make you happy any time of day

> Day, but not night

As long as the evil grey will just stay away

> As long as the moon stays away. Apparently the sun is biased against the moon and calls it evil.

As the eras go by I will have no choice but to eat you whole

> The sun will eat the earth when it becomes a red giant. Thanks @HWalters

Then after, I will turn white because I am done and full

> It will then become a white dwarf. Thanks @HWalters

Comment: Good job the "bring society to knees" refers to the G5 level of solar storms, more likely to occur during the solar maximum, which can bring society to its knees because of years of blackouts. The "kill" part refers to black holes and neutron stars, which can kill you if you get too close. Sorry if this was easy

Comment: Methinks that the sun will turn into a [Red Giant](https://www.google.com/search?q=sun+will+turn+into+red+giant&oq=sun+will+turn+into&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.11039j1j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and that the evil grey refers to clouds, not the moon...

Comment: @Chowzen Thanks. HWalters probably said red giant originally and I misread. But now he deleted his comment so I can't check. I think evil grey as the moon makes more sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Is this:

> Facebook

I am not sure about my answer but I think it can get a chance.

Comment: No but good guess